# get array parameter from what user type in browser

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

how to get array parameter from what user type in browser with codeigniter3

this is my controller

```
class header extends CI_Controller{
    public function index(){

        $this->load->model('header_model');
        $hasil = $this->header_model->getData();
        var_dump($hasil);


    }
}
```

and this is my model

```
class header_model extends CI_Model{
    public function getData(){

        $array = ["000118","000112","000117"];
        $this->db->select('NOMOR_DAFTAR, TANGGAL_DAFTAR');
        $this->db->where_in('NOMOR_DAFTAR',$array);
        return $this->db->get('tpb_header')->result_array();
    }
}
```

$array above i want to get from what user type in browser

Answer (score 0):

You can use **header(‘content-type application/json’)** in codeigniter to return json array.

**For example:**

```
class header extends CI_Controller{
    public function index(){
        header("Content-type:application/json");
        $this->load->model('header_model');
        $hasil = $this->header_model->getData();
        //var_dump($hasil);
        echo json_encode($hasil);


    }
}
```

Comment: not like that.. example if user type is brower http://localhost/app/header?Nomor_daftar=["000118","000112"]  what i want is i want to get thoose value (118 and 112) and put into parrameter @array

Answer (score 0):

finally i got the answer, but for note this not using codeigniter pure, there is librabry since method get there is no in codeigniter pure
and this is the answer

```
class Header_model extends CI_Model {
public function getData($array = []){
     $this->db->select('NOMOR_DAFTAR, TANGGAL_DAFTAR');
     $this->db->where_in('NOMOR_DAFTAR',$array);
     return $this->db->get('tpb_header')->result_array();
 }}

class header1 extends Rest_Controller{
public function index_get(){
    $array[]=$this->get('NOMOR1');
    $array[]=$this->get('NOMOR2');  
    $this->load->model('header_model');
    $hasil = $this->header_model->getData($array);
    var_dump($hasil);
}}
```